# The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable error in eclipse

Tags: java, android

```
public class CustomBlockFactory
{
private static final Logger logger = 
Logger.getLogger(TableListControllerFactory.class.getName());

public static AndroidTourController getController(TourControllerParameters 
paramTourControllerParameters, TourSequencer paramTourSequencer)
{
((CustomBlock)paramTourControllerParameters);
return new EnableTableController(paramTourControllerParameters, paramTourSequencer);
}
}
```

I'm getting error at ((CustomBlock)paramTourControllerParameters); as "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable".

Could anyone please rectify this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the first line of the method supposed to do?

Comment: CustomBlock c = ((CustomBlock)paramTourControllerParameters);return new EnableTableController(c, paramTourSequencer);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to cast the parameter `paramTourControllerParameters` to type `CustomBlock` so that you can call the `EnableTableController` constructor. However your code won't work because the cast operator does *not* change the static type of a variable.

Instead you can create a new variable with the desired type and assign the result of the cast operator to this variable:

```
public static AndroidTourController getController(
    TourControllerParameters paramTourControllerParameters,
    TourSequencer paramTourSequencer)
{
    CustomBlock customBlock = (CustomBlock)paramTourControllerParameters;
    return new EnableTableController(customBlock, paramTourSequencer);
}
```

Alternatively you can omit the temporary variable and write both the cast and the constructor call in a single statement:

```
return new EnableTableController(
    (CustomBlock)paramTourControllerParameters,
    paramTourSequencer);
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you're doing nothing with this code

```
((CustomBlock)paramTourControllerParameters);
```

Maybe you wanted do this?

```
return new EnableTableController((CustomBlock) paramTourControllerParameters, paramTourSequencer);
```

Answer (score 2):

`((CustomBlock)paramTourControllerParameters);` will cast paramTourControllerParameters into CustomBlock , so you need to store it into new variable like

```
CustomClock customClock = ((CustomBlock)paramTourControllerParameters);
```

Comment: Given the code provided, they don't need to store it in a variable at all. They're not doing anything with it other than passing it through as a parameter to a constructor, so they can do the cast then instead.